# textbox having value via javascript, but asp:requiredfieldvalidator fires even the textbox has the value

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

i have a textbox in asp.net with required field validator, which is filled using the javascript function(). But the case is that when the validation fires on the textbox it gives error message if it is empty thats okey, but when i fill textbox via javascript it still shows the error message of validation

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide your code in you comment.

but i have understand little bit of your question.

try this and comment your require field validator on your textbox.

and use this javascript function in your code and let me know it working correctly or not.

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBxID" onblur="return validateTextBox()"></asp:TextBox>`

```
<script type="type/javascript>

function validateTextBox(){
   if ($("#txtBxID").val() == "") {
      $("#txtBxID").css("border", "1px solid red");
      return false;
   } else {
      $("#txtBxID").css("border", ""); 
   }
}
</script>
```